# Image Filling and Centering in Circle shape

Tags: html, css, image, geometry

I'm trying to get my image to center and fill the circle shape (without stretching the image). Currently i only have the image taking up half the circle. 
You can see my website here - http://anglican.koru.firebrand.co.nz/

Images will be uploaded by clients so i'm unable to have the 'background-image' in the css as it will constantly be changing.

Thanks

Comment: Please write the part of code, you tried for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of you added `max-width` to your image, that makes the image fitted to the circle width.

remove `max-width` and add

```
max-height: 100%; // this is for fit the height of image to circle
margin-left: -50%; // this is for centering the image
```

to `.img-responsive`

Comment: ah, this css works for landscape image, if you added portrait image, please use ```max-width``` and ```margin-top```

Answer (score 0):

Change `height:auto` to `height: 100%;` for `.img-responsive`

```
.img-responsive {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 100%;  //changed this
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `max-width:100%;` from `.img-responsive` class then will get circle.